# When does a socket stream reading return?

Tags: java, android, sockets

Let me use the following example to explain my question:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(); 
socket.setReceiveBufferSize(64*1024);
socket.connect(AddressOfSomeStreamingWithEndlessData, 6000);
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[64*1024];
while(true)
{
   //When does the underlying reading decide to return?
   int iRead = inputStream .read(byteBuffer);
}
```

I am wondering how the system decides to return inputStream .read(byteBuffer). It does not wait till byteBuffer is filled, neither does it return immediately when there is a byte. Is this highly device dependent?

[Update]:

I used essentially the above code and did some tests on two different Android tablets and a simulator to receive data from a streaming source. Here is my observation for **this particular scenario**:

inputStream .read(byteBuffer) returns one or multiple TCP payloads. Payload here means the data section of TCP segment (i.e. TCP packet minus TCP header). The payload size apparently varies, and can be as small as one byte if that is what the source sends. However, there seems to be an upper limit far smaller than the Window size (in this case it is 65536) offered by the receiver. That seems to vary too between 1000 and 1500. For example, for one configuration, it is 1460, so iRead is 1460, 2920, 4380, 5840, .... For another one, it is 1448. I wan to emphasize that I am **reporting my observation, not generalizing anything** here.

Comment: Dependent on the network, TCP configuration and multitude of other things, so don't attempt to write any code that depends on its behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I think this comment plus an example of a specific configuration would be a good answer to this question.

Comment: @ben75 It wasn't just 'not relevant for `Socket` input stream'. It was wrong for ***all*** input streams. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It blocks at least one byte has been received, or end of stream or an exception occurs. If data has been received it then transfers all that data, up to the limit specified by the code, and returns the count of bytes transferred. How much that is depends entirely on how much data had been received, which you cannot predict or control in any way.

See the Javadoc.

Comment: I have done some testing, and it has never returned one byte.  For the streaming source I am testing, it returns at 1K bytes. I am wondering why it does not return 1 byte, 2 bytes, 3 bytes, 100 bytes, 500 bytes, ...

Comment: Hong.  If you wrote an application that wrote 1 byte to a socket and waited, then the application that read from the other end would get that 1 byte ... without waiting for the next one.

Comment: Maybe my question is not very clear.  I was asking about the situation where the server has endless data.  I indicated by "AddressOfSomeStreamingWithEndlessData".  Maybe I should emphasize this in my question.

Comment: @Hong It doesn't make any difference. The contract of read() is what I stated. It's in the Javadoc. That's all you can assume. Write your code accordingly.

Comment: @Hong [In case you can't see the deleted answer] Of course it isn't random, and of course it depends on the system. Nobody has said otherwise. Specifically, it depends entirely on how much data has arrived when you call read(), or, if none, on how much arrives when it unblocks. See my answer. Your 1448 is almost certainly the TCP payload of the path MTU, i.e. a single IP packet. Clearly your server isn't sending any faster than you are receiving.